# Qt Translations: What context should I use in the ts file for standard buttons like OK, Save, Cancel?

Tags: c++, qt, macros, translation

I don't want to use Qt's qm file. I want to generate my own qm files for different languages. I tried using context like **QDialogButtonBox**, **QDialog**, but still the button text is still untranslated. I have used code like:-

`static const char* const messages[] = {
    QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("QDialogButtonBox", "OK"),
    QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("QDialogButtonBox", "Cancel"),

};`

Answer (score 1):

First, add this:

```
QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("QDialogButtonBox", "&OK"),
QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("QDialogButtonBox", "&Cancel"),
```

Second, go to `qt-src/translations/qt_<lang>.ts`, open `QDialogButtonBox` section and add everything from there, you are using.